# How to Return Nested Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to return the `result` parameter from the `getColumn` function.  When logging, it returns undefined.

The connection function connects to a SQL DB and the query returns a data set.

How can I pass the variable back up the promise chain?

```
getColumn = function(columnName, table) {
  sql.connect(config.properties)
    .then(result => {
      let request = new sql.Request();
      request.query("SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + table)
      .then(result => {
          // want to return this result from the getColumn function
          return result
      }).catch(err => {
          // Query error checks
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      // Connection error checks
    })
} // 

console.log(getColumn('username', 'Login'))
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `return` in front of `sql.connect()` and `request.query()`? That might just work. `getColumn()` will return a Promise though so you'll need another `then` there.

Comment: then resolve that promise and get the result or you might need to use callbacks

Comment: Ok, then do something like `getColumn('username', 'Login').then((result) => console.log(result));`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you can't return a value directly form `getColumn()`.  The insides of that function are asynchronous so the value won't be known until AFTER `getColumn()` returns.  You are currently getting `undefined` from `getColumn()` because it has no return value.  The `return` you do have is to an asynchronous `.then()` handler, not for `getColumn()`.  There is no way to return the final value from `getColumn()`.  It's asynchronous.  You have to either return a promise or use a callback.  Since you're already using promises internal to the function, you should just return a promise.

You can return a promise from `getColumn()` and use `.then()` or `await` with that promise to get the value.

To return a promise, you need to return the internal promises:

```
const getColumn = function(columnName, table) {
  // return promise
  return sql.connect(config.properties).then(result => {
    let request = new sql.Request();
    // chain this promise onto prior promise
    return request.query("SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + table);
  });
} // 

getColumn('username', 'Login').then(val => {
   console.log(val);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: OK. Since it's async will I not be able to pass the results into another function and loop over the array?  I am trying to make a utility function that I can use as an intermediary to update column values.

Comment: @Matthew - You never directly return async results from a function.  Just can't do it in Javascript.   You return promises instead.  You can use `await` to loop over the array calling an async function that returns a proimse.  But, we can't really help with that part of the problem because you didn't show any of that code.  I think I've answered what you originally asked.  Perhaps you should accept this. research using `await` in a loop and then, if you get stuck, write a new question about how to use `getColumn()` in a loop.