# How to get value of an array from a field in Firestore (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want the value of the array stored in Firestore, but when I run this code, I always get back "*undefined*".

```
function getKey(collection, index) {
    db.collection(collection).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            return (doc.data().maxLessons[index])
        });
    });
};

console.log(getKey("fix", 2))
```

---

Edit:
My expected output is the number 2 of the array stored in a field (maxLessons).
The array is:

```
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 6}
```

So in the code, I want to get the 2 `maxLessons[index]` (index=2)

---

we also tried to store the result in an global array, but this didn't worked because it always creating an local array.

Feel free to ask for more information :)
Thank you for responding.

Comment: With ´doc.data()´ you'll get the fields of the document each round (of the forEach-loop)

Comment: Could you edit your post and include your expected output? I tried replicating your code and I encountered problems with `maxLessons[index]`. Also to clarify, you intend to list a field stored in a document am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the field is stored in a document (https://paste.pics/4885816e6cc5c0ee86c2ef5a978696e4)

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083278/how-to-return-nested-promise) could help.